# Find out if the logarithm of the dependent variable is used in lm

Tags: r, glm, lm

Say I have two `lm` models in R:

```
m1 <- lm(log(Volume) ~ Height + log(Girth), data = trees)
m2 <- lm(Volume ~ log(Girth), data = trees)
```

What is the standard way to find if the dependent variable is logged, i.e. would return `TRUE` for `m1` and `FALSE` for `m2`?

Comment: Try `any(grepl('log', attr(terms(m1), 'variables')[[2]]))`

Comment: This is a good answer but it will search, I think, whether any variable is logged rather than just the dependent.

Comment: @KeesMulder no, it will search for the dependent variable

Comment: A variant would be `grepl('log', as.list(attr(terms(m1), 'variables')[[2]])[[1]])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not directly saved as a TRUE/FALSE flag in the model object.

A way to make this work would be

```
grepl("log", names(m1$model)[[1]]) 
grepl("log", names(m2$model)[[1]])
```

which will search for the word "log" in the model part of the lm-object.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to check whether the dependent variable is log-transformed.

```
grepl('log', as.list(attr(terms(m1), 'variables')[[2]])[[1]])
#[1] TRUE
grepl('log', as.list(attr(terms(m2), 'variables')[[2]])[[1]])
#[1] FALSE
```